# Convert Code Academy Battleship Code to python 3.2

Tags: python

I was working on the code academy battleship code and I need to figure out a way to convert it into python 3.2 It works perfectly fine in 2.7, but doesn't work in 3.2
Here's what I have so far:

```
import random

board = []

for x in range(0,5):
  board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
  for row in board:
    print (" ").join(row)

print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
  return random.randint(0,len(board)-1)

def random_col(board):
    return random.randint(0,len(board[0])-1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)
guess_row = input("Guess Row:")
guess_col = input("Guess Col:")

print ship_row
print ship_col

if (guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col):
    print ("Congratulations! You sank my battleship!")
else:
     if guess_row < 0 or guess_row >= len(board) or guess_col < 0 or guess_col >= len(board):

        print ("Oops, that’s not even in the ocean.")
    else:
        print ("You missed my battleship!")
        guess_row = ("X")
        guess_col = ("X")
        print_board(board)
    if board[guess_row][guess_col] == ("X"):
        print ("You guessed that one already.")
```

Like I said, it works in 2.7 but not in 3.2
In 3.2 I get a syntax error for print ship_row
Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the help
Unfortunately, it now says unindent does not match any outer indenation level, highlighting 
else:
        print ("You missed my battleship!")
        guess_row = ("X")
        guess_col = ("X")
It's probably really simple. but I'm a complete beginner at this

Comment: Seems like the line `if guess_row < 0 or guess_row >= len(board) or guess_col < 0 or guess_col >= len(board):` is indented 1 space too much maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print statement is replaced with print() function in 3.x

```
Old: print "The answer is", 2*2
New: print("The answer is", 2*2)

Old: print x,           # Trailing comma suppresses newline
New: print(x, end=" ")  # Appends a space instead of a newline

Old: print              # Prints a newline
New: print()            # You must call the function!

Old: print >>sys.stderr, "fatal error"
New: print("fatal error", file=sys.stderr)

Old: print (x, y)       # prints repr((x, y))
New: print((x, y))      # Not the same as print(x, y)!
```

is an extract from documentation.
http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 the `print` statement has been replaced by the `print()` function.

new `print(ship_row)`

old `print ship_row`

See this:
[What’s New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function)